# Convert SQL Left Join to Linq Expression Left Join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, left-join

I have a query from SQL and I'm doing a left join. It's working ok.

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Comments, Table1.IdListDef  
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Id = Table1.IdListDef  
LEFT JOIN Table3  
ON Table1.Id = Table3.IdComments  
WHERE Table1.IdListDef = 36 and Table2.IdRev = 1075 and Table3.IdAutor IS NULL
```

I need to transfrom this query to Linq Expression from C#. How can I do it? I don't know how to transform this query that contains left join.

Comment: Please never just dump SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think. Especially navigation properties are important with joins. You probably don't need any `join` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
var result = (
    from item1 in table1
    join item2 in table2 on item1.IdListDef equals item2.Id
    join item3 in table3 on item1.Id equals item3.IdComments into finalGroup
    from finalItem in finalGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where item1.IdListDef == 36 && item2.IdRev == 1075 && finalItem.IdAutor == null
    select new
    {
        item1.Id, item1.Comments, item1.IdListDef
    }).ToList();
```

Addition to your comment, if you're willing to see if any item has id of your outer parameter you could use linq *Any* extension method:

```
bool idExists = result.Any(item => item.id == idAutor);
```

Comment: Really good! It worked! Thank you!
Do you know how to put a count in this select?
Now I want to count if idAutor exists, if not it will bring count = 0. The IdAutor is coming from parameter now.

Comment: @Victor You want to see if any item1.Id from the result equals your outer IdAutor parameter?

Comment: Got that working on my code, thanks. Note to Microsoft: Worst. API. Ever.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS QUERY

```
    VAR OBJLIST=(FROM A IN CONTEX.TABLE2
        FROM B IN CONTEX.TABLE1.WHERE(X=>X.IdListDef==a.Id && B.IdListDef==36 && B.IdRev==1075 )
        FROM C IN CONTEX.TABLE3.WHRE(X=>X.IdComments==a.Id).DefaultEmpty()
        where  C.IdAutor==NULL
        select new{a.Id, a.Comments, a.IdListDef }).ToList()
```

Comment: This won't compile, C# is case-sensitive.